# How to access the "hidden" style attrabute using javascript and protractor

Tags: javascript, html, css, automation, protractor

I have a webpage with a search. If the search is invalid using data such as special characters then a warning message appears.

When the page loads the CSS loads as follows:

`<div class="searchError" id="isearchError" style="display: none;">`

When you input invalid text and press search the above changes to
`display: block; opacity: …;` 
and that also brings up a `<div class="marker"></div>` with an error message.

I have tried the following `var styleValue = element(by.id('ideliveryareaerror')).getCssValue('style');` but I get a tree structure of the element.

Example of my code:

```
        var styleValue = element(by.id('isearchError')).getCssValue('style');
        browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
        browser.sleep(1000);
        console.log(styleValue);
        browser.sleep(1000);
```

What I want to do is:

- Get the style attributes value (Should be none)
- Press enter with invalid data
- Get the style attributes value (Should be block)
- Get error message text

Image of my code:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `getCssValue('style')`, but you want `getCssValue('display')`. [`getCssValue`](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getCssValue) gets the **CSS** value, not an HTML attribute. (I don't use protractor, but the method name and what you were asking for jumped out at me. :-) )

So something like:

```
var searchError = element(by.id('isearchError'));
expect(searchError.getCssValue('display')).toBe('none');
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
browser.sleep(1000);
expect(searchError.getCssValue('display')).toBe(''); // Or possibly 'block' or one of the others
console.log(styleValue);
browser.sleep(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the `isDisplayed` method protractor gives you?
If you expect the element to be displayed/not displayed you could go like this:

```
expect(element(by.id('ideliveryareaerror')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);  // (or false)
```

Additionally, you are getting the tree structure of the element because `getCssValue` is a promise that needs to be resolved, that's why it might not work with plain `console.log`
In that case, you'd need to go like this:

```
var styleValue = element(by.id('isearchError')).getCssValue('style')
    .then( function(style) {
        console.log(style);
    });
```